# Add images / pictograms on OpenSearch Dashboards

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am a newbie creating an OpenSearch Dashboard. I wonder whether it is possible to customise the axis of the charts that are created. For example, if I was representing information based on countries, would be possible to add images or pictograms about flags? [image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So I am not sure that you can put images there (without writing a custom plugin that is). What you could do is enrich the name fields with their respective countries flags. This transform could be done with a scripted field from OpenSearch Dashboards or if you are using fluentbit you could use a calculated field with a [dict mapping](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/modify).